# .exe not getting executed via winrm

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, winrm

I am trying to run a exe via pywinrm. Architecture is as follows:

```
code --> host Machine (1)--> another machine where exe is located(2)
```

I can connect to host machine 1 via code and execute echo statements there. But when i try to execute exe by

```
session.run_cmd('start \\machine2IP\path\to\exe\filename.exe')
```

It's not working. The same command is working when I manually open machine 1's cmd and run.

I tried adding -Wait parameter, running with & and with run_ps as well. But still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a lot of trial and error but it worked for me.

```
session.run_cmd('\\\\machine2IP\path\to\exe\filename.exe')
```

I removed start from the beginning and used 4 '' instead of 2 ''. And it worked for me.